# Laravel Livewire change Jquery class name inside component

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

Here i have a `component` which i want to change `jquery` class/id name, all of my `jquery` codes into `<script>` tag don't update after change class/id names

for example:

```php
class OrderFormComponent extends Component
{
    public string $current_span = '';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.front.order-form-component');
    }
}
```

view:

```html
    @push('scripts')
        <script>
            $("{{$current_span}}").removeClass("active-process");
            

            $("#section-2").on("click", ".next-level-2", function (e) {
               @this.set('current_span', '#pstep-1>span');
            });
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>
```

here i want to change `current_span` variable to `#pstep-1>span` by clicking on `#section-2` and use that in `$("{{$current_span}}").removeClass("active-process");`

when i put `$("{{$current_span}}").removeClass("active-process");` outside of `script` it work fine

Comment: Why do you need a Livewire property for this? Seems overly complex